# How do I say "on her/his/their mother/father's side" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, usage, single-word-request

How do I say "She looks like her aunts on her mother's side"?

> Sie sieht wie ihre Tanten mütterlicherseits aus.

I cannot use *mütterlicherseits* in this case because that would mean "on my mother's side". How do I say "on her mother's/father's side"?

Comment: To me it's okay. Mütterlicherseits refers to the mother of whichever person you've established before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Mütterlicherseits* and *väterlicherseits* are absolutely correct.
You can use them in third person singular, as you did in your example.