# How do I talk about my parent's parent?

Tags: english-to-german

How would I say my mother's/father's father? Or would I have to say my granddad on my mother's/father's side? I do not want to say my granddad as I want to talk about them separately.

Comment: **To close voters:** please state in comments what you felt was unclear or off-topic instead of downvoting or giving unhelpful and entirely unrelated comments. Especially new user may need some guide on what you expect them to write in their question, and **we do not need** to say in each and every question that a German expression was sought, that should be self-explaining here.

Comment: I do not see any mention of the German language in the question.

Comment: @CarstenS: this is **German** Language Stack Exchange, where everything is related to the German language. To mention that in each and every question would be rather superfluous. It is safe to assume that we look for a German expression even if it was not mentioned.

Comment: You should have used a dictionary, looking up maternal or paternal. Clearly general reference.

Comment: @Em1, eine Frage mit einem mütterlichen Onkel hatten wir hier schon, wenn ich mich recht erinnere ;)

Comment: @Em1: there is no such thing as a "maternal father" or a "paternal mother" in English - a general dictionary may not be of much help if you don't already **know** how we express this in German.

Comment: @Takkat, the question is not how to say “on my mother's side”, just whether to use that construction. Otherwise it would be a duplicate, btw.

Comment: @Takkat Who said "maternal father"? I didn't. But "maternal grandfather" equals "mother's father". So, using a [dictionary](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=maternal&l=deen&in=&lf=de&cid=&srt=null) would not only give you the term "mütterlichseits" but also a translation for "maternal grandfather" so that you can easily translate this to "mein Großvater mütterlichseits". So, what's your point?

Comment: @CarstenS Yes, it is about the terms maternal and paternal. And so you're right that it is a dupe. http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9619/1224 ### http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9758/1224

Comment: JFTR, I voted to close as duplicate, not off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

You would say

> Der Vater meiner Mutter

or

> Mein Grossvater mütterlicherseits / väterlicherseits

Both is commonly used.

Answer (score -2):

The German vocabulary for grandparents is very much like the English one. Unlike in, for example, Swedish, there is no special word for, say, mother's father.

Comment: There's not a single word but you can still express it. -1

Comment: @Em1, of course, you can, I just as in English.